# Build app Error XamlG and Bundle in my first App with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm new in developing with xamarin. I started to develop an app with a Xamarin.Forms and obviously I have some problem:

Errors:

> The target "XamlG" does not exist in the project. App.Android
>
> The name 'bundle' does not exist in the current context. TApp.Android

I already tried on google and I did the following tests :

1. Update the nuget Pack
2. Clean and rebuild the solution

But that doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

BR

Comment: Delete the folder bin and obj.Then rebuild your project maybe your issue will been solved.

Comment: Thanks for support.. After I have deleted the folders and recompiled obtain : "The name 'bundle' does not exist in the current context." only ... I repeat again but persist the error.